# The relationship between Fourier coefficients of function $f$ and its continuity

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-series, continuity

How to prove that if Fourier series of function $f$ converge uniformly, then function is continuous?

Comment: If you mean that the Fourier series converges uniformly to $f$, then this simply follows from the fact that a uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: I'm sorry, Fourier series, not coefficient. 
If for $f(t)$ exists Fourier series that converge uniformly $\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z} }{c_k e^{(-2i\pi kt)}}$ on $[0,1]$ then $f(t)$ is continious.

Comment: @M Turgeon yes i know this theorem, but is this theorem true under $\mathbb{C}$ - functions?

Comment: @user31919 see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

In general, a uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous (this is proven in any introductory course in analysis, and it holds in any metric space). Now, if the Fourier series of $f$ **converges uniformly to** $f$, we can thus conclude that $f$ is continuous. However, in general, your Fourier series could converge uniformly **without converging to** $f$, and so your result, as stated, is false (for example, you can modify your function on a set of measure zero without changing your Fourier series).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you really look for is the following

**Lemma** Given a sequence $f_n$ of continuous complex valued functions defined on a compact set $E$, then $f_n$ converges uniformly if and only if $\operatorname{Re}f_n$ and $\operatorname{Im}f_n$ converges uniformly.

**Proof** To see this, just take the supremum in the following 
$$|\operatorname{Re}f_n(x) - \operatorname{Re}f(x)|^2\leq|f_n(x)-f(x)|^2=|\operatorname{Re}f_n(x) - \operatorname{Re}f(x)|^2+|\operatorname{Im}f_n(x) - \operatorname{Im}f(x)|^2$$
The imaginary part in the same.

Thus the complex valued version of the theorem mentioned by M Turgeon, follows from the real version and vice versa.